# Finding linear fits in a scatter plot efficiently

Tags: r, optimization, scatter-plot

i have a list of points

```
   n     x
   7     99.06
  12    100.45
  25     98.11
  42    106.92
  75    106.78
  94    102.34
 128    119.05
 145    116.54
 149    116.06
 167    111.49
 173    112.69
 195    120.25
 201    119.70
 217    107.62
 233    105.53
 239    107.86
 257    109.77
 287    115.71
```

This is the scatter plot and what i want to achieve
[image: the scatter plot]

I want to find all linear lines that cross more then two points.
what i have is the blue dots - what i want to find is the red lines.

the simple solution is to run `lm` on all combination and filter the top ones by adjusted R squared. but, there are a lot of combinations and it's taking a very very long time . i've tried elimination by setting a limit on the angles between the sections but it's not significant enough. plus, i ran into some problems when i had a long line including other significant segments as illustrated by 1/2 in the graph.

I would appreciate any new ideas.

Comment: there are lightweight alternatives to `lm` that do less work and are considerably faster (the Rcpp family has several examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it with `lm` and it takes me less than two seconds to find all matches. Is that too long for you? If not, here's how I did it. I create a vector of all the 816 combinations of three points in your data and loop through it. When the r-squared is above 0.9999, I plot the line.

With this criteria, I get more fits on the left of the chart and a few on the right are not present. It seems that in your chart, some fits are not optimal. You might want to check that out

```
library(zoo)
data1 <- read.table(text="
2012-01-11  99.06
2012-01-19 100.45
2012-02-07  98.11
2012-03-02 106.92
2012-04-19 106.78
2012-05-16 102.34
2012-07-05 119.05
2012-07-30 116.54
2012-08-03 116.06
2012-08-29 111.49
2012-09-07 112.69
2012-10-09 120.25
2012-10-17 119.70
2012-11-12 107.62
2012-12-05 105.53
2012-12-13 107.86
2013-01-10 109.77
2013-02-25 115.71")
data1 <-zoo(data1[,2],as.Date(data1[,1]))
plot.zoo(data1, type="p", col="blue", pch=16)

my.comb <-combn(data1, 3,simplify = FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(my.comb)){
vect <- my.comb[[i]]
reg <-lm(coredata(vect)~index(vect))
if(summary(reg)$adj.r.squared>0.9999) lines(my.comb[[i]], col="red")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two seconds is fine - The way i did it took much longer. in your solution you don't offer connection of more then three points. i'm actually willing to lower the threshold for R-Squared if more points are connected on a relatively reliable line. this is why i used the Adjusted R Squared.

Comment: In the code I provided, the lines after the plot command add lines to the chart. You could repeat that block to add lines that connect with 4 points like this: `my.comb <-combn(data1, 4,simplify = FALSE)` I've tried it with combinations of six points and it takes about 40 seconds. Doing it for 3,4,5,6 points in the same chart should take a minute or two. You should also experiment with changing the threshold in `if(summary(reg)$adj.r.squared>0.9999)`